# Added Restivus and Iron Router docs appear

Tags: meteor

I'm new to meteor and added Restivus to my project. It works OK, but there is the IRON ROUTER doco at the bottom of the page.

[image]

It's not in the template ... how can I remove it?

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
   // Global config
   Restivus.configure({
      useAuth: false,
      prettyJson: true
   });

    Restivus.addCollection(Players);


  if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
     players = [{ name: "Shane Warne", order: 'Ristretto' },
                 { name: "Mimi Macpherson", order: 'Expresso Forte'},
                 { name: "Cathy Freeman", order: 'Lungo Forte'},
                 { name: "Eric Bana", order: "Lungo Leggardo"}];
     _.each(players, function (player) { 
        Players.insert(player); 
     });
  }
});
}
```

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

**EDIT**

This seems to be the issue ... not sure why it is still in the package

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues/43

Comment: This sounds like the issue but did not solve it: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1180

Comment: I've updated my answer now that v0.8.0 has been published, officially resolving this issue. You can probably accept the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that pesky Iron Router stuff! It's [already been removed](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/pull/46) in an unpublished version that should be out in about two weeks. You can grab an early version from the [0.8.0 branch](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/tree/0.8.0) on Restivus, if that's too long to wait.

**UPDATE: As of v0.8.0, the `iron:router` dependency has been removed and all `iron:router`-related issues have been resolved, including the one described here.**